# Error: uninitialized constant FFI::Platform::CPU on starting jekyll server

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, jekyll-theme

I got the below error on trying to start Jekyll server

> Error:  uninitialized constant `FFI::Platform::CPU`

I tried reinstalling Jekyll server and its dependencies, but no luck. Could someone help me to get around this issue? Thanks.

I am using **ubuntu=18.04**, **jekyll=3.8.6**

```
anil@anil:~/customer-churn$ jekyll serve


Configuration file:
  ~/customer-churn/_config.yml
  Source: ~/customer-churn
  Destination: ~/customer-churn/_site
  Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
Generating... done in 0.597 seconds.

jekyll 3.8.6 | 
Error:  uninitialized constant FFI::Platform::CPU
```

Comment: FWIW, _Jekyll_ has no server.

Comment: Try `bundle exec jekyll serve`.

Comment: I also tried **_bundle exec Jekyll server_** but issue not solved showing the same error again                                                                                                          g

Comment: Have you run `bundle install` there _before_?

Comment: yes, I installed bundle before starting the server

Answer (score 11):

I guess this problem occurs if you've installed *Jekyll* through `apt`. In that case a `bundle update` won't work immediately after an `apt remove`. Try the following approach:

Uninstall *Jekyll* first:

```
sudo apt remove jekyll*
```

Clean-up your dependency libs:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Then in your project directory run:

```
bundle update
```

Positively, then `jekyll serve` should work for you.

Comment: Don't forget the `apt autoremove`! without, it will not work!

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to solve this simply by running `bundle update` or reinstalling jekyll and dependencies with apt as other answers suggested.

What did work was to

- remove all versions of jekyll and dependencies with `sudo gem uninstall ...`,
- remove jekyll and all dependencies with `apt-get remove ...`,
- then reinstall jekyll and dependencies with `apt-get install ...`,
- and then run `bundle update` in the project directory.

Then only `bundle exec jekyll serve` works, and `jekyll build` still presents the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by reinstalling the Jekyll and its dependencies using some steps which are given in the below link -

> http://michaelchelen.net/81fa/install-jekyll-2-ubuntu-14-04/

I just want to thanks all who have to help and giving guidance to me from your busy schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing Jekyll using apt (if you've installed it that way):

```sh
sudo apt remove jekyll*
```

Then go to your project, type:

```sh
bundle update
```

and only then:

`jekyll serve`

Found this answer here:
https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/jekyll/jekyll/7712/502572155

Comment: Don't forget to ``sudo apt autoremove`` after the first step!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.   After running `bundle exec jekyll serve --trace`, I noticed that some packages were being loaded from the `/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby` directory.  So, I removed the `/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby` directory (keeping a backup copy of it in my home directory, just in case). This, followed by `bundle install`, fixed the issue for me.